# SSIS conditional split, but want to check a pattern

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Please see the below flowchart.

[image]

How can i really achieve it. It tried various things in the SSIS Expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regular expressions then you could use a Script Component to fill a (new) column and then use a Conditional Split to filter on that column. Or you could redirect the 'good' and 'bad' rows to their own output within the Script Component itself. Here is an example of that. It redirects bad email addresses to an other output: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/03/regular-expressions-in-ssis.html
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming any number from 0 to 99999 should be considered 'True', then you can attempt a cast and redirect the error row to 'False' if the cast to integer fails. Example:

your conditional split will be False when

```
(DT_I4)[Column1] > 99999
```

and your data flow should look like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks Jayvee, 
How can we deal with complex pattens?

Like, look for 009-78-901212, or Just alphabets etc?

Comment: There is no reg exp component in SSIS as such; you can always have workarounds for specific cases as this one  to find numbers we’ve just done. You can also use other string functions like findstring, token/tokencount (in ssis 2012), etc for particular cases but if your requirements are broader than checking for one or two conditions, then I’d suggest using a Script Component to do the work in C# or VB.NET.