# Conditional Split & Derived columns project

Tags: ssis

im working on a project where I  need to:

1. copy "Employee" table from DB to Excel worksheet destination (Only columns needed are ID, FirstName,LastName).
2. Create new column "Seniority" (based on HireDate I guess):
   a) worker that works less than a year, will be "Junior".
   b) worker that works between one year to five years , will be "Veteran".
   C) worker that works more than five years, will be "Senior".
3. Workers that their first name starts with "An" should be excluded and not be on the destination file.

The features that allowed are Conditional Split & Derived columns.
I succeeded in first subject but find it difficult to do the rest, will be glad if you'd assist here..
Thanks!

Comment: On #2, you marked your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630867/failure-in-adding-new-transformed-column) on how to compute years of service as solved. Is that not providing the years a person has been working there?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the 3rd condition :

> Workers that their first name starts with "An" should be excluded and
> not be on the destination file.

You can use a simple query like below (since you didn't mention your DBMS, make sure that the syntax is the suitable one for your need) :

```
SELECT ID, FirstName,LastName FROM YourTable
WHERE FirstName NOT LIKE 'An%'
```

Or you can use  [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754312/ssis-conditional-split-but-want-to-check-a-pattern) then you could use a Script Component to fill a (new) column and then use a Conditional Split to filter on that column.

Next, you can use a Conditional Split and then map the output to the column Seniority :

**Case 1 : worker that works less than a year, will be "Junior"**

```
DATEDIFF("YEAR",[HireDate],GETDATE()) <=1
```

**Case 2 : worker that works between one year to five years , will be "Veteran"**

```
DATEDIFF("YEAR",[HireDate],GETDATE()) >1 AND DATEDIFF("YEAR",[HireDate],GETDATE()) <=5
```

**Case 3 : worker that works more than five years, will be "Senior"**

```
DATEDIFF("YEAR",[HireDate],GETDATE()) >1 AND DATEDIFF("YEAR",[HireDate],GETDATE()) <=5
```

Or you can use a simple query in your source component :

```
 SELECT ID, FirstName,LastName, 
 
 CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,[HireDate],GETDATE()) <=1 THEN 'Junior'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,[HireDate],GETDATE()) > 1 AND DATEDIFF(YEAR,[HireDate],GETDATE()) <=5 THEN 'Veteran'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,[HireDate],GETDATE()) > 5 THEN 'Senior'
    ELSE 'Not applicable'
END;

 FROM YourTable
```